# Hashing Django password in a simple login form

Tags: django, passwords, frame

I have a login with password django web, to have a secure website I want to hash my password and username, which codes should I apply? here is my login.html

```
<p>{{ error }}</p>
<form action="/cat_app/login/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    {{ form.username.error }}{{ form.username }}<br>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    {{ form.password.error }}{{ form.password }}<br>
    <input type="submit" class="button" id="loginButton" value="MEOW"/>
    <li><a href="/cat_app/register">Register</a></li>
</form>
```

Comment: Hashing is not done in your template. Django provides views and forms to handle user authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Under no circumstances** should you attempt to do any hashing yourself. Django includes an authentication framework with a good secure implementation, and you should simply use the models, forms and views provided there.

Answer (score 0):

Django provides a flexible password storage system and uses PBKDF2 by default.

Authentication should be done in your **views.py** using `authenticate()`.

Please see Django's [User Authentication Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests) for more info.